# Reflected waves and phase changes

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions

If a wave passes from a lightweight string to a higher density string, we say that the reflected wave has a pi phase change.
Can we say that it has minus pi phase change? If yes, why would that not change anything?

Comment: Think about $\sin(\phi + \pi) = \sin(\phi + \pi - 2\pi) = \sin(\phi - \pi)$

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with sinusoidal solutions, everything is "modulo two pi". Mathematically, a phase shift of $+\pi$ and a phase shift of $-\pi$ give rise to exactly the same wave form.

So the answer to your question is **yes** - you can say either "it has $\pi$ phase change" or "it has $-\pi$ phase change", and it describes exactly the same phenomenon.

Think about it this way: if something has been going around in circles since the universe began, and you ask "how many turns have you made?", whether the answer is 123,456,789,000 or 123,456,789,001 will not change the motion you observe...

Note that "real" waves have a beginning and an end, and therefore have to be thought of as a superposition of (infinitely many) waves. Each of these waves in turn would undergo these phase shifts, and when you add it all up it still gives exactly the same result.